# How can I run multiple batch files concurrently in different locations from a single 'master' batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

These different batch files are functioning fine when executed individually, but for convenience I have been trying to execute them all at once from one location to save me from navigating through the many different sub-folders to execute them one by one.

I would have thought that my first testing attempt featuring a few of the batch files would work:

```
    CALL "C:\Steam\steamapps\common\Sins of a Solar Empire Rebellion\GameInfo\Sins_text_to_bin.bat"
    CALL "C:\Steam\steamapps\common\Sins of a Solar Empire Rebellion\Mods-Rebellion v1.83\Enhanced 4X Mod - Git Clone\GameInfo\Sins_text_to_bin.bat"
    CALL "C:\Steam\steamapps\common\Sins of a Solar Empire Rebellion\Mods-Rebellion v1.83\Star Wars Interregnum - Git Clone\GameInfo\Sins_text_to_bin.bat"
```

But when I ran this nothing happened besides the cmd window appearing for a split second and then closing, with none of the referenced batch files executed.

After multiple attempts, the only thing that half worked was:

```
    cd "C:\Steam\steamapps\common\Sins of a Solar Empire Rebellion\GameInfo"
    CALL "Sins_text_to_bin.bat"
    cd "C:\Steam\steamapps\common\Sins of a Solar Empire Rebellion\Mods-Rebellion v1.83\Enhanced 4X Mod - Git Clone\GameInfo"
    CALL "Sins_text_to_bin.bat"
    cd "C:\Steam\steamapps\common\Sins of a Solar Empire Rebellion\Mods-Rebellion v1.83\Star Wars Interregnum - Git Clone\GameInfo"
    CALL "Sins_text_to_bin.bat"
```

But that does not run the batch files concurrently; instead it executes them one after the other.

I know I'm probably missing something elementary here, but I am pretty much an illiterate pleb with stuff like this, so please be kind ;)

Comment: use the `start` command instead of `call`. See `start /?` for help.

Comment: So, exactly like my first attempt, but with "call" replaced with "start"? That just brings up three separate cmd windows and nothing starts

Comment: The command `start` interprets the first double quoted string as title for the command prompt window. Therefore specify explicitly first a title and then the rest of the command. The title string can be also an empty string, i.e. the command line begins with `start ""` and then the command follows.

Comment: I meant when I said I'm an illiterate pleb with this stuff, so you're going to have to practically spell it out for me. Are you saying to write  "start", followed by the filepath, followed by the "call" command to the "Sins_text_to_bin.bat" file?

Comment: @KennyTheKlever please read the help of [start /?](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html). Take a special look at the `/D` parameter. No [call](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) needed at all here.

Comment: @Stephan It's just not giving me the help I need. What do I put as the title, for example? All I want is for it to start different batch files which are all in different locations; I'm sure it's something simple that I haven't tried but won't be able to guess on my own. Could you please type it out if you know, in a more understandable way than the cmd help yields?

Answer (score 1):

Below command could meet your expectation. 'master' batch file look like

```
START "C:\Steam\steamapps\common\Sins of a Solar Empire Rebellion\GameInfo\Sins_text_to_bin.bat" CALL "C:\Steam\steamapps\common\Sins of a Solar Empire Rebellion\GameInfo\Sins_text_to_bin.bat"
START "C:\Steam\steamapps\common\Sins of a Solar Empire Rebellion\Mods-Rebellion v1.83\Enhanced 4X Mod - Git Clone\GameInfo\Sins_text_to_bin.bat" CALL "C:\Steam\steamapps\common\Sins of a Solar Empire Rebellion\Mods-Rebellion v1.83\Enhanced 4X Mod - Git Clone\GameInfo\Sins_text_to_bin.bat"
START "C:\Steam\steamapps\common\Sins of a Solar Empire Rebellion\Mods-Rebellion v1.83\Star Wars Interregnum - Git Clone\GameInfo\Sins_text_to_bin.bat" CALL "C:\Steam\steamapps\common\Sins of a Solar Empire Rebellion\Mods-Rebellion v1.83\Star Wars Interregnum - Git Clone\GameInfo\Sins_text_to_bin.bat"
```

Comment: I seem to be getting closer with this one. The 'master' batch file now brings up 3 cmd windows, but it seems to only want to run the referenced batch files in wherever the 'master batch file is. So for example, I made the master batch file on my desktop, and it seems to only want to run the three referenced batch files on the desktop itself, rather than in each of the three different locations where the referenced batch files are.

Answer (score 1):

to `call` a command means, execute it, wait until it is finished before continuing.
to `start` a command means, execute it in another instance of `cmd` and continue without waiting for it to finish.

So if you want to execute several programs in parallel, you should use `start`. The first quoted parameter is the title of the new instance (can be empty: `""`). The `/D` parameter gives a working directory. Filenames/paths with spaces have to be quoted. So the final line would look something like:

```
start "title" /d "<my folder>" "<my program>"
```

or in your case:

```
start "" /D "C:\Steam\steamapps\common\Sins of a Solar Empire Rebellion\GameInfo" "C:\Steam\steamapps\common\Sins of a Solar Empire Rebellion\GameInfo\Sins_text_to_bin.bat"
```

Comment: Thanks for the more in-depth explanation, but I got it working how I wanted in a slightly different way. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!

The attempt that I posted above in the second code window that I said "half worked" was close. It seems that the `call` command when used in this way forces the first batch process to finish before the next one begins.

If you want all of your referenced batch files to execute concurrently as I do, then the `start` instead of the `call` command is what will work:

```
   cd "\directory\bat1\"
   start bat1.bat
   cd "\directory\bat2\"
   start bat2.bat
   cd "\directory\bat3\"
   start bat3.bat
```

Which in my specific case using my example attempts earlier looks like this:

```
    cd "C:\Steam\steamapps\common\Sins of a Solar Empire Rebellion\GameInfo"
    start Sins_bin_to_text.bat
    cd "C:\Steam\steamapps\common\Sins of a Solar Empire Rebellion\Mods-Rebellion v1.83\Enhanced 4X Mod - Git Clone\GameInfo"
    start Sins_bin_to_text.bat
    cd "C:\Steam\steamapps\common\Sins of a Solar Empire Rebellion\Mods-Rebellion v1.83\Star Wars Interregnum - Git Clone\GameInfo"
    start Sins_bin_to_text.bat
```